# i need to run two set of data in single adf pipeline at 2 different times using single trigger

Tags: azure, parameters, triggers, pipeline

I need to run two set of data taken from database in single azure data factory pipeline at 2 different times in a day using single trigger

i want to run the pipeline run twice a day, for 2 different data in 2 different times a day

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your requirement, you can use two copy activity in the single pipeline to copy data from two sources to respective sinks and add trigger to that pipeline in two different time.

1. Create a pipeline with two copy activities, one for each set of data you want to copy. Configure each copy activity to copy data from the appropriate source to the appropriate destination.

[image]

2. Create a trigger for the pipeline. Click Add trigger in the pipeline and select New/Edit.
   [image]
3. In the trigger settings, Set the type as "schedule" trigger. Set the recurrence to " Every 1 Day" and set the start date to the first time you want the pipeline to run. Then, add two schedules in the "Execute at these times" .

[image]

4. Click Ok.
5. Make sure to Publish the pipeline for trigger to be activated.